# Android rx concat map on a queue

Tags: android, rx-android

I created a download service that receives a list of items and for each item executes a function and receive an observable, this observable tells that the operation finished.

To do this, I created an observable that receives the list size and execute concatMap, see working code below:

```
Observable.range(0, list.size()).concatMap(
   //foreach item call a download function
   //...)
```

But client came with another request, he says that this list could change its size, for example, a high priority item could be added to this list.

I think that I need to use queue for this. How could I proceed to use concatMap with a queue??

Tks,